# How to find what is causing a preventDefault which overrides normal click behavior

Tags: javascript

I've inherited some large piece of code. Somewhere inside a way too generalised `e.preventDefault()` is prohibiting the normal behavior of an anchor click.

I thought about running profiler in Chrome webtools to see what is happening when clicking on a particular link, hoping to trace it back to the culprit statement. However I haven't had much luck

how can I trace back (if possible) a statement that is overriding normal click behavior, when clicking a link in Chrome webtools?
(I am using jQuery)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You should be able to override `Event.prototype.preventDefault` and add a `debugger` statement as its first line.

Run the following via the console.

```
var oldEPD = Event.prototype.preventDefault;
Event.prototype.preventDefault = function() {
    debugger;
    oldEPD.call(this);
};
```

Comment: brilliant - life saving jist!

Answer (score 1):

Based on techfoobar answer, here's modern and more advanced version that is quite useful to debug event-related problems. Note it expects you to be using a modern env JS like Webpack/Babel but you can certainly make the same work with older JS syntax.

It's basically the same except the log message is more user-friendly. I try to compute a "meaningful selector" that will help you debug the problem:

> click.stopPropagation() on section#nav-bar > a.Tappable-inactive.group-link.nav-bar-item.my-main-team > div.nav-bar-item-content > svg

```
// Logs all calls to preventDefault / stopPropagation in an user-friendly way
if ( process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ) {
  (function monkeyPatchEventMethods() {

    const logEventMethodCall = (event,methodName) => {
      const MinimumMeaninfulSelectors = 3; // how much meaningful items we want in log message
      const target = event.target;

      const selector = (function computeSelector() {
        const parentSelectors = [];
        let node = target;
        let minimumSelectors = 0;
        do {
          const meaningfulSelector = node.id ?
            `#${node.id}` : node.classList.length > 0 ?
              `.${Array.prototype.join.call(node.classList, '.')}` : undefined;
          if ( meaningfulSelector ) minimumSelectors++;
          const nodeSelector = `${node.tagName.toLowerCase()}${meaningfulSelector ? meaningfulSelector : ''}`;
          parentSelectors.unshift(nodeSelector);
          node = node.parentNode;
        } while (node && node !== document && minimumSelectors < MinimumMeaninfulSelectors);
        return parentSelectors.join(" > ");
      })();

      console.debug(`${event.type}.${methodName}() on ${selector}`,event);
    };

    const preventDefault = Event.prototype.preventDefault;
    Event.prototype.preventDefault = function() {
      logEventMethodCall(this,'preventDefault');
      preventDefault.call(this);
    };

    const stopPropagation = Event.prototype.stopPropagation;
    Event.prototype.stopPropagation = function() {
      logEventMethodCall(this,'stopPropagation');
      stopPropagation.call(this);
    };

  })();
}
```

https://gist.github.com/slorber/b1c0ffef56abd449c05476b5c609a36e

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the various `preventDefault()` answers here, you can also see if in your HTML code, you're returning `false` at your link's `OnClick` event-handler, like that:

```
<a href="#" onclick="DoSomething(); return false;"></a>
```

If you do, just remove it (It's `true` by default):

```
<a href="#" onclick="DoSomething()"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe search your code on `e.preventDefault` and adding a breakpoint to that line. You can read the call stack when the breakpoint is triggered and you can possibly see what code overrides the click.

Comment: Sure, wanted to do that as well- but I am wondering if it is possible to use profiler, or timeline to really trace back the offending line.