# Updating anchor-links in the URL bar

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a click function that will update the URL bar with a URL-address, but only for anchor links.

Because the condition is only for anchor links; I've used a method by first filtering all anchor links into an array and then filter the array even further by matching strings in the href and if it's matched, it should add a click event to all matching links and update the URL when the link is clicked.

So far it works, but I'm wondering if this is the right way to go about it. Specifically on using href.substr.

I've been dabbling a little bit with jQuery in the past before, but want to write scripts with no library reliance.

**However my script solution might also be superfluous**, as the problem could lie within some other script that prevents anchor-links to update in the URL bar... I'm not really sure on how to go about it with bug-tracking.

```js
const allAnchorlinks = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='#']");
  allAnchorlinks.forEach(function(perAnchorlink) {
    if (perAnchorlink.href.substr(-4) === "test") {
          perAnchorlink.addEventListener('click', function() {
            location.href = "http://localhost/project/#test";
            //alert("works!");
    });
       //console.log('perAnchorlink: ', perAnchorlink);
        }
});
```

Comment: Side note : Using `location.hash = 'test` is simpler if using on same page. Similarly all `<a>` have a hash property `perAnchorlink.hash` or inside the event handler `this.hash`

Comment: Not understanding if there is an actual problem here or not. In one place you say it works and another says there might be a problem. If other links have a hash value and the url is not changed when clicked then they are preventing default event action either with `event.preventDefault()` or returning false in their handler

Comment: Ah, yes thanks for recalling my memory on preventDefault. This set me on the right track to find the right tool for the job and find the cause in no time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490931/how-to-find-what-is-causing-a-preventdefault-which-overrides-normal-click-behavi